# Outlook download attachments with MAPI python based on date, sender and subject line

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am completely new to I am trying to download attachments using MAPI based on date, sender's email address and subject line.

Below is my code:

```
import datetime 
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders
val_date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-&y")
today = msg.Senton.date() = val_date
inboxtime = all_inbox and today
email_sender = 'Email input here'
sub_today = 'Subject line input here'
att_today = 'attachment name input here'

for msg in inboxtime:
    if msg.SenderEmailType == "EX":
       if msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.find(email_sender) != -1
           break
else:
       if msg.SenderEmailAddress.find(email_sender) != -1 and msg.Senton.date() == val_date:
          break
For att in msg.Attachments:
if att.FileName == att_today:
   break
try:
    att.SaveAsFile('D:\\' + att.FileName)
    print(True)
except:
    print(False)
```

However, it shows below error:

```
today= msg.Senton.date() == val_date
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Senton'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is not MAPI - this is Outlook Object Model. Secondly, you are assuming there are only `MailItem` objects in the Inbox folder - but you can also have `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem`, etc. Make sure first that you really have a `MailItem` object - check if the `Class` property == 43 (`olMailItem`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, but found out it was my syntax. Changing
`Senton` to `SentOn` cleared the error.